# List all terms except terms that have the product catalog visibility set to hidden on Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, woocommerce-theming

In the code below I can list all the terms belonging to the `pa_brand` taxonomy.

If no product is associated with the term, it will be an empty term, therefore it will not be listed.

However, if a product is associated with the term but has the **catalog visibility** setting to **hidden**, the term will be full and will be listed.

I'm looking for a way to not list a term that has all products hidden in the catalog.

Best regards to all.

```php
add_shortcode( 'product_attributes', 'get_product_attributes' );

function get_product_attributes() {
    
    $attribute_name = 'pa_brand';
    
    $terms = get_terms([
        'taxonomy' => $attribute_name,
        'hide_empty' => true,
    ]);
    
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $terms )){
    
        $html = '<ul>';
    
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                
                $link = get_term_link( $term->slug, $attribute_name ) ;
                $html .= '<li><a href="' . $link . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
            }
        
        $html .= '</ul>';
        
        return $html;
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use a `WP_Query` to check if any product associated with each term has the catalog visibility set to hidden or not.

Answer (score 0):

Place the following function in functions.php

```
function get_visible_attribute_terms($attribute_type) {
    $args = array(
        'visibility' => 'catalog',
        'return' => 'ids',
    );
    $visible_product_ids = wc_get_products( $args );

    $visible_attribute_terms = array();
    if (!empty($visible_product_ids)) {
        $visible_attribute_terms = get_terms(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $attribute_type,
                'hide_empty' => false,
                'object_ids' => $visible_product_ids,
            )
        );
    }

    return $visible_attribute_terms;
}
```

How to use it:

```
$visible_terms = get_visible_attribute_terms('pa_color'); //Replace with attribute you want to check

foreach ($visible_terms as $term) {
    echo $term->name;
}
```